# How to return a C-array from method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a function that returns a variable and I want to know how to return an array the issue is it isn't an NSArray it is just an average C array like this...

```
-(b2Fixture*) addFixturesToBody:(b2Body*)body forShapeName:(NSString*)shape
{
    BodyDef *so = [shapeObjects objectForKey:shape];
    assert(so);
       FixtureDef *fix = so->fixtures;
    int count = -1;
    b2Fixture *Fixi[4];
    while(fix)
    {

        count++;
        NSLog(@"count = %d",count);
        Fixi[count]= body->CreateFixture(&fix->fixture);
        if (Fixi[count]!=0) {
            NSLog(@"Fixi %d is not 0",count);
        }
        if (body->CreateFixture(&fix->fixture)!=0) {
            NSLog(@"body %d is not 0",count);
        }

        fix = fix->next;

    }

    return *Fixi;

}
```

If you see some variable types you don't know it's because I'm using cocos2d framework to make a game but I'm returning a variable of b2Fixture... This code compiles however only saves the value of the first block of the array "fixi[0]" not the whole array like I want to pass

anyhelp :) thankyou

Comment: If you're going to return a C array (of anything), where do you intend to allocate it? (Hint: It can't be on the stack of the called function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a local array.  You'll need to do some kind of dynamic allocation or pull a trick like having the array inside a structure.

[Here is a link](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx5.html) to an in-depth article that should help you out.

Comment: And how would I go about doing that

Comment: [`malloc(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/malloc.3.html), perhaps?

Comment: A very true answer but ... should be expanded or reference one of the myriad of other answers.

Answer (score 2):

In general returning C arrays by value is a bad idea, as arrays can be *very large*. Objective-C arrays are by-reference types - they are dynamically allocated and a reference, which is *small*, is what is passed around. You can dynamically allocate C arrays as well, using one of the `malloc` family for allocation and `free` for deallocation.

You can pass C structures around by value, and this is common, as in general structures tend to be *small* (or *smallish* anyway).

Now in your case you are using a small array, it has just 4 elements. *If* you consider passing these 4 values around *by value* is reasonable and a good fit for your design then you can do so simply by embedding the C array in a C structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    b2Fixture *elements[4];
} b2FixtureArray;

...

-(b2FixtureArray) addFixturesToBody:(b2Body*)body forShapeName:(NSString*)shape
{
    BodyDef *so = [shapeObjects objectForKey:shape];
    assert(so);
    FixtureDef *fix = so->fixtures;
    int count = -1;
    b2FixtureArray Fixi;
    while(fix)
    {   
        count++;
        NSLog(@"count = %d", count);
        Fixi.elements[count]= body->CreateFixture(&fix->fixture);
        if (Fixi.elements[count] != 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Fixi %d is not 0",count);
        }
        if (body->CreateFixture(&fix->fixture) != 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"body %d is not 0", count);
        }

        fix = fix->next;    
    }    
    return Fixi;    
}

...

// sample call outline
b2FixtureArray result = [self addFixturesToBody...]
```

Whether this standard C "trick" for passing arrays by value is appropriate for your case you'll have to decide.

*Note: If `b2fixture` is an Objective-C object make sure you understand the memory management implications of having a C array of objects references depending on the memory management model (MRC, ARC, GC) you are using.*

Comment: how would I retrieve the struct that it's returning i.e. before I would write b2fixture = function now what? since its a struct and all... do I need to make a new struct of the same type

Comment: I get an error something along the lines of b2Fixture can't be saved as b2FixtureArray incompatible type

Comment: @KingPopsicle - the last line shows how it can be called. What this standard C technique does is wrap an array as the single member of a structure. So instead of `array[index]` you use `structure.array[index]` everywhere. The error you're getting sounds like you're trying to assign a b2Fixture to the structure instead of to an element of the array within the structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to design function or method that has to return a fixed or limited size array, one possibility is to pass a pointer to the result array to the function or method as a parameter.  Then the caller can take care of allocating space, or just use a local or instance variable array.  You might want the called function to sanity check that the array parameter isn't NULL before using the array.